# Any way to optimize the running time? Trying to add data to a new column from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

I've got 2 dataframe: Nodes and Edges.
The edges DF only contains the From ID and to ID, my goal is to add two more columns (From Age, To Age) in order to do some statistics. the age data sits in the Nodes DF.
**There are about 1.2M of nodes and 14M of edges in the dataframes**

right now this is how I'm trying to make it happen:

```
edges['From Age'] = np.nan
for i in range(len(edges)):
   edges.loc[i+1, 'From Age'] = int((nodes.loc[nodes['ID'] == (edges.iloc[i])['From']])['Age'])
```

This is taking ages (went hours without finishing) and I can't find or think of more efficient way to work this out.
Please give me some guidance.

**An example slice of my data (after I filtered irrelavant rows like ID=2:

```
ID,Gender,Region,Age
1,1.0,"zilinsky kraj, zilina",26.0
3,1.0,"bratislavsky kraj, bratislava - karlova ves",29.0
4,0.0,"banskobystricky kraj, brezno",26.0
5,1.0,"zilinsky kraj, zilina",26.0
6,0.0,"zilinsky kraj, zilina",38.0
```

And few edges:

```
From,To
1,6
1,3
1,4
1,5
```

Comment: Can you update the question with information on the initial number of rows of `nodes` and `edges`? (Not sure what you mean by 'there are 14M of edges'. Also include a few rows of both dataframes.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuysv hey, Nodes df has about 1 Million of rows, and edges about 14 million rows. added a picture of the head of each df

Comment: Please post it as text, so that it can be copy/pasted for experiments.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys Hey, posted as text the first few rows of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have integer id's starting from zero you can just:

```
# Create some example dataframes
n_nodes=int(10E6)
n_edges=int(1.4*10E6)
edges = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'From': np.random.randint(0,n_nodes,size=n_edges), 'To': np.random.randint(0,n_nodes,size=n_edges)})
nodes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Age': np.random.randint(18,90,size=n_nodes), 'ID': np.random.permutation(np.arange(n_nodes))})

# assuming you have integer ID's:
nodes.sort_values(by="ID", ascending=True, inplace=True)
edges['Age From'] = nodes['Age'].to_numpy()[edges['From'].to_numpy()]
edges['Age To'] = nodes['Age'].to_numpy()[edges['To'].to_numpy()]
```

It took less than 1s for me (excluding generating all those random numbers).
The idea is that if you index an array with an integer array it pulls out the value at that specific location example:

```
np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])[np.array([0,0,1,3,3,2], dtype=int)]
```

return `array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C'], dtype='<U1')`

---

The problem with your code is, that `nodes['ID'] == (edges.iloc[i])` creates a new array with 1M entries at each iteration!!!

---

If you have string or other id's you can try converting to category first. This takes about a minute for me with most of the time being spend on the first three lines:

```
nodes['ID']=nodes['ID'].astype('category')
edges['From'] = edges['From'].astype(nodes['ID'].dtype)
edges['To'] = edges['To'].astype(nodes['ID'].dtype)
edges['Age From'] = nodes['Age'].to_numpy()[edges['From'].cat.codes.to_numpy()]
edges['Age To'] = nodes['Age'].to_numpy()[edges['To'].cat.codes.to_numpy()]
```

Comment: I like the idea very much. though getting some issues with it..
My ID's start from the number 1 and they arent in a full sequence (because they are after dillution of unrelevant ages).
Now I'm getting: IndexError: index 1138318 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1138314
And that's probably because the ages narray start at index 0 though the ages start from 1 and not all of them show. I thought about shifting the array but that will cause issues with the lower id's (like 1,3,4 etc).

Comment: Ok my bad, I figured I will use your idea before I filter the unneeded rows and then take them out.

Works like charm very fast! I gotta improve my numpy skills